# WAMP SERVER Command Prompt SET PATH=%PATH%

Tags: php, mysql, apache, windows

My WAMP SERVER will not connect to website in wamp server after I went to command prompt and typed in PATH=%PATH% is there any way to revert this??? 
I'm an idiot I admit it.

Comment: Do I need to set Path=%path%; Then add C:/wamp64/php  to it???? >.<

Comment: All services are green